# PowerShell Customer header containing AD query

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to get these Custom headers to display correctly when bringing in content from `Import-CSV`

The CSV contains a column titled Surname with a Surname in each row, it also contains a header titled "Email" with no data in any of the cells below.

```
$csv = Import-csv C:\temp\tester.csv

$csv | select Surname,@{Name='Email';Expression={Get-ADUser -Filter 'Surname -like "$_.Surname"' | Select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName}}
```

executes correctly when I hardcode the surnames in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enclose the filter in single quotes, this prevents Powershell from substituting `$_.Surname` for a value. If a string is enclosed in single quotes, it is treated as is, without any attempts to replace symbols, including escape symbols, prior to passing the string as an argument or an expression result. Replace the expression with this:

`` Expression={Get-ADUser -Filter "Surname -like `"$_.Surname`"" | Select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName} ``

The backticks are used to escape the quotes that should be passed into AD filter.